# Heroku / Bundler / Push issue: Could not find rake-0.8.7 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, heroku, bundler, git-push

For the life of me I can not figure out how to fix this issue. I have looked around for the whole day and found simular issues but they all seem to be slightly different.

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Rails app detected
-----> Configure Rails to log to stdout
   Installing rails_log_stdout... done
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.7
   Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
   Using --without development:test
   Your Gemfile doesn't have any sources. You can add one with a line like 'source:rubygems'
   Could not find rake-0.8.7 in any of the sources
   FAILED: http://docs.heroku.com/bundler
!     Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler

error: hooks/pre-receive exited with error code 1
To git@heroku.com:smooth-wind-620.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:
```

Bundle install and bundle list both have rake listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding something like `source 'http://rubygems.org'` to the top of your Gemfile, or `source :gemcutter`?  That's the first error I see heroku giving you and would be the first thing I would try to resolve.

Comment: OK.. I would like to thank you and kick myself in the head for not seeing the issue.